# jq - count number of items matching select

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to count the number of records that match some property.

If I have json like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

I am trying to get the number of records with a count of 1.

I can get the matching records with:

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.count == 1)' in.json
{
  "id": 0,
  "count": 1
}
{
  "id": 1,
  "count": 1
}
```

But the output lists two items, so I cannot directly use `length` to count them. Instead, using length gives the length of each item.

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.count == 1) | length' in.json
2
2
```

How can I count how many records were matched by `select`?

Comment: Trick is to transform the thing you want into a single representative array and then use `length` on that structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For efficiency, one should avoid using `length` on a constructed array.  Instead, it's preferable to use a stream-oriented approach.

Here's one efficient solution, which, for convenience, uses the generic `count` function, defined as:

```
def count(stream): reduce stream as $i (0; .+1);
```

With this def, the solution is simply:

```
count(.[] | select(.count==1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `jq 'map(select(.count==1))|length' in.json`.

See `select` example in `jq` manual: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your `select` in square brackets `[]`.

```
jq '.[] | [select(.count == 1)] | length' in.json
```

I think this is the simplest answer, as compared to those already given.