# Use kubectl find out how many Deployments don't have a container called "main"

Tags: jq, kubectl

I want to be able to quickly figure out how many Deployments in a namespace don't have a container named "main".

This is as close as I have got so far, using jq, which gives me a list of all container names:

```bash
kubectl get deploy -o json | jq '.items[].spec.template.spec.containers[].name'

"main"
"main"
"healthchecker"
"main"
"main"
"service"
"main"
"main"
```

The problem with that is, I can't see which containers belong to which Deployments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jq - count number of items matching select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618271/jq-count-number-of-items-matching-select)

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. I.p., a small but telling example of the input to jq would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below command would print the deployment name and the container names. `grep -v` would filter out whatever you need to remove.

```
kubectl get deployment  -o custom-columns='"DEPLOYMENT-NAME":.metadata.name,"CONTAINER-NAME":.spec.template.spec.containers[*].name'

DEPLOYMENT-NAME   CONTAINER-NAME
foo               httpd
foobar            nginx
foobar007         nginx
foobar123         nginx
zoo               nginx,main
zoo1              busybox,main
```

The above command may be further modified to trim the output header.

```
kubectl get deployment --no-headers -o custom-columns='"":.metadata.name,"":.spec.template.spec.containers[*].name'
foo               httpd
foobar            nginx
foobar007         nginx
foobar123         nginx
zoo               nginx,main
zoo1              busybox,main
```

Comment: Thank you, I has to add single quotes around the custom-columns param but then this works well for my needs

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `.metadata.name` :

```
kubectl get deploy -o json |
  jq -r '.items[] | "\(.metadata.name) \(.spec.template.spec.containers[].name)"'
```