# jq: How to count number of values that match a condition?

Tags: jq

Working with a large hash, something like:

```
{
  "1": {
    "marked": true,
    "id": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "data": "blah",
    "marked": true
}
```

I'd like to just count the number of entries (two) which are marked, with "marked" property as true.

Attempt:

```
❯ echo '{  "1": { "marked": true, "id": 1  }, "2": { "id": 2  }, "3": { "id": 3, "data": "blah", "marked": true }}' | jq '.[] | select(.marked==true) | length'                                          experiment/git-ci-artifact-view[✦]47ed9707a[✎✭]22m
2
3
```

What's happening here is I'm getting shown that the first item that matches has 2 props and the second item has 3 props. Since I've converted the large object into an array with the initial `.[]`, and the filter has properly eliminated the second entry from this.

I could obtain the answer with a `wc -l` but the point of the question is how to get to the answer of `2`, e.g. id's 1 and 3 make for two items that are marked true.

I tried a bunch of stuff, the most promising, `.[] | [select(.marked==true)]'` just produces this though, wrapping each item in `[]`:

```
[
  {
    "marked": true,
    "id": 1
  }
]
[]
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "data": "blah",
    "marked": true
  }
]
```

Various stuff that seems like it would make sense don't parse, such as `.select(.marked==true)`.

Comment: Alright I made a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/62618271/340947

Comment: Your code would work on an array of values, but you're passing in an object whose properties you want to filter/count.

Comment: Yeah which if i just wanted to count those values i could just call `length` but i was having trouble counting the length after applying a filter.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in `jq '.[] |= select(.marked==true)'`. Alternatively/Equivalently, `map_values`.

Now to find out what this does and why it works.